# app.config not loading when App is on StartUp

Tags: c#, app-config, startup

I have a problem. If I run my application by clicking on it, it loads the saved app.config settings.

However, I need to have the Application run at Startup. Got this working too, but when it loads it does not load the saved settings - just the default ones.

The first time my Application loads with the default settings I require the user to login to there account through a REST API, grab some data and store it. I then set

```
Properties.Settings.Default.is_installed = true
```

but when the app runs in Startup it loads the default (false).

Has anyone experienced this? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist changes to user settings `between application sessions`, call the Save method, as shown in the following code:

```
 Properties.Settings.Default.is_installed = true;
 Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

---

Here is [MSDN Reference 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397755%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

> Settings that are application-scoped are read-only, and can only be
>   changed at design time or by altering the .config file in between
>   application sessions. Settings that are user-scoped, however, can be
>   written at run time just as you would change any property value. The
>   new value persists for the duration of the application session. You
>   can persist the changes to the settings between application sessions
>   by calling the Save method.

Here is [MSDN Reference 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

> **Saving User Settings at Run Time:**
>
> Application-scope settings are read only, and can only be changed at
>   design time or by altering the .exe.config file in
>   between application sessions. User-scope settings, however, can be
>   written at run time, just as you would change any property value. The
>   new value persists for the duration of the application session. You
>   can persist changes to user settings between application sessions by
>   calling the Settings.Save method. These settings are saved in the
>   User.config file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. This is not a issue with Saving the settings. It won't READ the settings when the Application loads on Startup from a Registry

Comment: Means you already save settings but when you load application on startup your saved settings are not loading instead you are getting default settings.